# How customize Ubuntu installation

Tags: 12.04, installation, customization

How can I customize Ubuntu installation ? I don't want install Libre office or other app. I need something like Ubuntu server but without server tools .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The utterly simplest way is to install the Desktop version, then delete the un-needed apps in one pass with Synaptic. Select all excess applications, and have Synaptic do the work for you of removing the apps and their dependencies.

Otherwise, Ubuntu-Builder https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-builder allows you to strip out apps and dependencies, pre-installation. There's an established explanation here at [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)

Comment: ty , is Ubuntu-Builder reliable ? I want to install Ubuntu on my SSD

Comment: @sistyN, absolutely. I used it to customize 12.04 for my college and it was flawless. Just keep an eye out for the space though, recurring builds take a lot of space, make sure you clear your workpath each time.

Answer (score 1):

You want a minimal install to be able to install only what you require, the only issue is that is is not useful for installing in UEFI mode.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Comment: Can i use it with Ubuntu builder ?

Answer (score 1):

The more customization you want then the less ubuntu you need. I talking about Ubuntu minimal installation. Several times I have tried that .it just gives the core and everything you have to configure manually.

It will ask you while installation what software you would like to have , selected applications and tools only installs and nothing extra.